# I want to differentiate the subfolders and the files with is_dir() in laravel

Tags: laravel

I browsed a folder with

```
if ($path = opendir(public_path('images'))) {

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($path))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        echo $entry."<br>";
    }

    if(is_dir($entry)){
        echo "This is a folder!";
    }
}
closedir($path);}
```

And in this folder images I have sub folders and file. I want to differentiate the subfolders and the files of the folder images. i used is_dir($entry) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try given solution for you problem.

```
$subfolders = [];
$files = [];
if ($path = opendir(public_path('images'))) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($path))) {
        if (strpos($entry, '.') === false) {
            $files[] = $entry;
        } else if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $subfolders[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($path);
}
echo '<pre>';
echo "Subfolders : <br/>";
print_r($subfolders);
echo "Files : <br/>";
print_r($files);
exit;
```